# How to add servlet Filter with embedded jetty

Tags: java, jetty, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

I am embedding jetty into my app, and trying to work out how to add servlet filters (for cookie handling). The wiki and the javadoc's dont make it very clear, what am I missing:

```
Server server = new Server(port);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
FilterHolder f = new FilterHolder(new AuthorisationFilter());
context.addFilter(... f ...); // ?????
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new TestServlet()), "/");
```

The only info I have found on this is a [forum post suggesting the documentation](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jetty.support/14244) on this needs to be improved.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot define it within the web.xml file. I realize this is embedded but as long as you have the file in the classpath under WEB-INF/web.xml you should be fine.

Comment: I've not used web.xml for a long time, normally I just use servlet 3.0 spec annotations. I just don't enjoy mucking around with XML files.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Update: For Jetty version 9.2.2:

```
    Server server = new Server();

    // Note: if you don't want control over type of connector, etc. you can simply 
    // call new Server(<port>);
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setHost("0.0.0.0");
    connector.setPort(8085);
    // Setting the name allows you to serve different app contexts from different connectors.
    connector.setName("main");
    server.addConnector(connector);

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    // For development within an IDE like Eclipse, you can directly point to the web.xml
    context.setWar("src/main/webapp");
    context.addFilter(MyFilter.class, "/", 1);

    HandlerCollection collection = new HandlerCollection();
    RequestLogHandler rlh = new RequestLogHandler();
    // Slf4j - who uses anything else?
    Slf4jRequestLog requestLog = new Slf4jRequestLog();
    requestLog.setExtended(false);
    rlh.setRequestLog(requestLog);
    collection.setHandlers(new Handler[] { context, rlh });
    server.setHandler(collection);

    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Google guava way
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
```

Original answer ===

If you don't want to use web.xml then use this:

```
SocketConnector socketConnector = new SocketConnector();
socketConnector.setPort(7000); // Change to port you want
Server server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { socketConnector });

WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();

webapp.setContextPath("/"); // For root
webapp.setWar("/"); // Appropriate file system path.

// Now you can use the various webapp.addFilter() methods
webapp.addFilter(MyFilter.class, "/test", 1); // Will serve request to /test.
// There are 3 different addFilter() variants.

// Bonus ... request logs.
RequestLogHandler logHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog("/tmp/jetty-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log");
requestLog.setRetainDays(90);
requestLog.setAppend(true);
requestLog.setExtended(false);
requestLog.setLogTimeZone("GMT");
logHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);

logHandler.setHandler(webapp);

HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
handlerList.addHandler(logHandler);

server.setHandler(handlerList);

server.start();
```

If you do want to use web.xml, instead of the addFilter() methods, just make sure you have a WEB-INF/web.xml in your webapp root path with the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
   PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>filterName</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.x.y.z.FilterClass</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
        <filter-name>filterName</filter-name>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the 1 mean in `webapp.addFilter(MyFilter.class, "/test", 1)`. In my code I just ignored it and passed in NULL, that seems to also work.

Comment: The parameter with a value of 1 is the number of instances to launch at startup.

Comment: as I understood jetty 9.1.3, the last parameter is a EnumSet<DispatcherType>: Declared in ServletContextHandler
public FilterHolder addFilter(Class<? extends Filter> filterClass,String pathSpec,EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatches)

Comment: That's right. In version 9.x lots of api have changed.

Comment: can you add multiple filters on same path?

Comment: Here is my implementation. https://imgur.com/a/NKutChB Only the one implementing the Filter class works but not the ContainerRequestFilter. Can you please explain ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 the filter implementing "ContainerRequestFilter" is a Jersey filter not a Servlet filter like the other. You would need to wire the Jersey filter into the Jersey runtime (which is built on top of Servlets) for it to work.

Answer (score 28):

I got the same problem, but I think Καrτhικ's answer is too complex.  I found this easy way:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
context.addServlet(org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.class, "/");
context.addFilter(AppFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.INCLUDE,DispatcherType.REQUEST));

server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
server.join();
```

My jetty version is `8.1.14.v20131031`.

Comment: yep, the other answer has a whole lot of irrelevant stuff for the actual question.

Answer (score 5):

The `ServletContextHandler.addFilter(...)` methods are just convenience wrappers around the `ServletHandler.addFilter(...)` methods.  Provided that you only need one `<url-pattern>` they *are* quite convenient.  However, if you need more than one pattern or choose to use `<servlet-name>` instead, you will need something more like this:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
        ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

FilterMapping mapping = new FilterMapping();
mapping.setFilterName( "Foobar Filter" );
mapping.setPathSpecs( new String[] { "/foo/*", "/bar/*" } );
mapping.setServletNames( new String[] { "foobar" } );
mapping.setDispatcherTypes(
        EnumSet.of( DispatcherType.INCLUDE,DispatcherType.REQUEST ) ) );

FilterHolder holder = new FilterHolder( FoobarFilter.class );
holder.setName( "Foobar Filter" );

context .getServletHandler().addFilter( holder, mapping );
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated for java 11 instead of javax. use jakarta. and 11.0.3 for jetty

```
ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(DefaultServlet.class);
servletHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase","./resource");
servletHolder.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "false");
servletHolder.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly", "true");
servletHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/api/source/*");
FilterHolder f = new FilterHolder(new MyFilter());
servletHandler.addFilter(MediaFilter.class, "/api/source/*",     
EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```