# Cross domain Configuration in jetty

Tags: cross-domain, jetty

all
I have a problem.

I wanna how to cross domain configuration in jetty.
don't have web.xml file.

source here.

...
...

```
Server jetty = new Server();
    HandlerList hl = new HandlerList();
    hl.addHandler(sch);
    jetty.setHandler(hl);
    jetty.setThreadPool(new QueuedThreadPool(NumberUtils.toInt(config.getProperty("ambariplus.jetty.threadPoolSize"))));

    SelectChannelConnector conn = new SelectChannelConnector();
    conn.setMaxIdleTime(NumberUtils.toInt(config.getProperty("ambariplus.jetty.maxIdleTime")));
    conn.setPort(NumberUtils.toInt(config.getProperty("ambariplus.jetty.port")));

    MBeanContainer mbc = new MBeanContainer(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
    mbc.setDomain(config.getProperty("ambariplus.jmx.domain") + ".jetty");
    jetty.getContainer().addEventListener(mbc);
    jetty.addBean(mbc);

    jetty.addConnector(conn);
    jetty.setStopAtShutdown(true);

    try{
        jetty.start();
        logger.info("Jetty started at port {} on {}", conn.getPort(), "127.0.0.1");

        String s1 = StringUtils.substring(config.getProperty("ambariplus.jetty.rootServlet.contextPath"), 1);
        String s2 = StringUtils.substringBetween(
            config.getProperty("ambariplus.jetty.jerseyServlet.urlPattern"), "/", "/*");
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One standard technique is to implement a [servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). There are many such examples online, one is [here](http://javasantoshanand.blogspot.com/2013/09/servlet-filter-to-set-response-headers.html). To do what you want you just need to set the [CORS headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). The filter could be as simple as two lines to call chain.doFilter then set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the filter's response. Since you don't have a web.xml there is a Jetty way to configure filters, you can find many examples online such as this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390577/how-to-add-servlet-filter-with-embedded-jetty).