# Integrate SparkJava with Dropwizard Metrics Servlet

Tags: spark-java

Is is possible to (easily) run the [Dropwizard Metrics Servlet](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.3/manual/servlets.html) within SparkJava?

My only thought would be to provide Spark with an [external webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631294/how-can-a-native-servlet-filter-be-used-when-using-spark-web-framework), and I'd rather not do that.

TIA,
-Matt